# Batch to duplicate text lines including spaces

Tags: batch-file, spacing

I'm using Windows 7.
I need a batch file to copy the lines of one text file to individual files.
The batch file I've written so far works almost perfectly:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Counter=1
for /f %%x in (OriginalList.txt) do (
set "Line_!Counter!=%%x"
set /a Counter+=1
)

set /a NumLines=Counter - 1

Echo %Line_1% >A1.txt
Echo %Line_2% >A2.txt
Echo %Line_3% >A3.txt
Echo %Line_4% >A4.txt
Echo %Line_5% >A5.txt
```

The problem I have is that any lines of text that contain a space ie

```
C:\Users\My Account\Documents\LINE SAVING
```

saves as

```
C:\Users\My
```

How do I store the entire line??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem: a space is one of the standard delimiters of `for`. If you don't define the token, it defaults to one. So you get only a string up to the first space or comma or semicolon, ...

Solution: set the delimters to none (no delimiter):

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (OriginalList.txt) do (
```